# Check if date is greater than/less than

Tags: sql, oracle

```
to_char(to_date(A.PERMISSION_USE_DT, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) < to_char(to_date(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

`A.PERMISSION_USE_DT` is currently formatted as `04/12/2013`; I would like to check and match if the date is older than the system date. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If A.Permission_Use_Dt is a date type, there's no need to do the TO_CHAR/TO_DATE conversions. Just do this:

```
A.Permission_Use_Dt < SYSDATE
```

Note that SYSDATE also has a time component, so it's today's date and time *right now*. To compare just the date part of the values, do this:

```
TRUNC(A.Permission_Use_Dt) < TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```